# Firebase Database. Retrieve nested data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

**MY CURRENT CODES** (now its working)

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    petshopRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            petshopsList.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Petshops petshops = postSnapshot.getValue(Petshops.class);
                petshopsList.add(petshops);
            }

            CustomerPetshopAdapter adapter = new CustomerPetshopAdapter(CustomerViewPetshopActivity.this, R.layout.customlist_viewpetshop, petshopsList);
            lvPetshops.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

**QUESTION**:

Lets say i have

```
petshopRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Petshops");
```

How do I retrieve all data in Blue Circle (in my image above)

Comment: Are you looking for a specific shop or do you want to loop over all the shops?

Comment: @JamesPoag i just want to retrieve all shops.. but i'm stuck on how to access the deeper nodes

Comment: in Petshops.class you should have a variable type with the same name as your database structure. Petshops as you are calling it there is the main reference node of all the sub keys nodes, so in your POJO just declare all the fields that one key have, if you want more help please post your Petshop.class

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Or maybe I should say, I think your code should already do what you want. The `for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())` loops over each node under `Petshops` and reads a `Petshops.class` from it What's the problem when you run this code?

Comment: ohh i think i missunderstood the flow how to access the node.. before i have nested foreach, outer foreach for retrieve the key and inner for retrieve the data and put them to Petshops.class

Comment: it should have 1 for that loop through all the keys, and then in your petshop.class is where you bring out which element you want to catch from firebase

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve all the data using the once value event. Then you can loop through it to get each key and value. I'm writing this logic in nodejs, you can convert it into your java logic.
Example,

```
petshopRef.once('value', function(snap){   

snap.forEach(listData=>{     //list data will have top level auto generated keys

listData.forEach(element=>{
element.key // will be the key, in your case (brcat)
element.val() // will be the corresponding value to above key. in your case (3)

});
});

});
```